# Add extra action (recenter) to `org-forward-element`?

Tags: elisp

In org-mode, strike `M-}` which invoke `org-forward-element` is very handy to jump around.

However, the matching line always stay at the bottom. So I have to manually execute (recenter).

How could add the action (recenter) to `org-forward-element`?

I tried a decorator solution, but does not work.

```
(defun add-recenter(func)
  (lambda ()
    (func)
    (recenter)))
(setq org-element-forward (add-recenter org-element-forward))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(advice-add 'org-forward-element :after (lambda () (recenter)))
```

---

I first tried `(advice-add 'org-forward-element :after 'recenter)`, but that didn't work, because if the advice function being added (in this case `recenter`) is interactive, its `interactive` spec overrides that of the old function (`org-forward-element`), which causes an error since `recenter` generates one argument while `org-forward-element` takes zero arguments.

---

The reason your code doesn't work is that in Emacs Lisp variables and functions are in separate namespaces, just like Common Lisp and unlike Scheme.  This is sometimes described as "Lisp-2", as opposed to "Lisp-1".  See e.g. this article: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/lisp1_vs_lisp2.html

Basically every symbol has both a "value cell" and a "function cell".  `setq` changes the symbol's value cell, and calling a symbol, like `(foo)`, accesses its function cell. The corresponding Emacs Lisp code would be something like:

```
(defun add-recenter(func)
  (lambda ()
    (funcall func)
    (recenter)))
(fset 'org-element-forward (add-recenter (symbol-function 'org-element-forward)))
```

That is essentially what the `advice-add` call above does.

Comment: ty so much for your solution and kind-and-patient tutor.